# Folding a piece of paper with numbers in sequence

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

Divide a rectangular sheet of paper with a side length of 2 × 4 into eight 1 x 1 unit squares
and label them as shown in the sketch.

[image: A rectangle grid divided into four columns and two rows, with a single number in each cell. From left to right the top row is 1, 8, 2, 7. From left to right the bottom row is 4, 5, 3, 6.]

Then fold the sheet of paper along the boundaries of the square so that you get a square stack
of paper with the squares on top of each other in the order of their numbers. The top square in
the stack should therefore have the number 1, the next the number 2 and so on. The square with
the number 8 should be at the very bottom. The numbers can be upside down or on the back of the
sheet. However, the sheet of paper must not be torn or destroyed in any other way.

How do you fold the sheet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it can be done as follows:

> Fold the rectangle along its length, making a 1x4 rectangle. Roll it up into a cylinder with 1827 on the outside, slot the end with 6&7 inside the other end between the 1&4. Tighten the cylinder until it has a circumference of 2 units, which puts the 6&7 between the 5&8 and the 2&3 between the 1&4. If you now flatten the cylinder  you should have all the numbers in order.